# PowerShell: Select line preceding a match -- Select-String -Context issue when using input string variable

Tags: string, powershell, match, select-string

I need return a line preceeding a match on a multi-line string variable.

It seems when using a string variable for the input Select-String considers the entire string as having matched.  As such the Context properties are "outside" either end of the string and are null.

Consider the below example:

```
$teststring = @"
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
"@

Write-Host "Line Count:" ($teststring | Measure-Object -Line).Lines #verify PowerShell does regard input as a multi-line string (it does)

Select-String -Pattern "line3" -InputObject $teststring -AllMatches -Context 1,0 | % {
$_.Matches.Value #this prints the exact match
$_.Context #output shows all context properties to be empty 
$_.Context.PreContext[0] #this would ideally output first line before the match
$_.Context.PreContext[0] -eq $null #but instead is null
}
```

Am I misunderstanding something here?

What is the best way to return "line2" when matching for "line3"?

Thanks!

Edit:
Additional requirements I neglected to state:
Needs to provide the line above ALL matched lines for a string of indeterminate length.  EG when searching the below for "line3" I need to return "line2" and "line5".

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line3
line6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`Select-String`** operates on *arrays* of input, so **rather than a *single, multiline string* you must provide an *array of lines*** for `-Context` and `-AllMatches` to work as intended:

```
$teststring = @"
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line3
line6
"@

$teststring -split '\r?\n' | Select-String -Pattern "line3" -AllMatches -Context 1,0 | % {
  "line before:  " + $_.Context.PreContext[0]
  "matched part: " + $_.Matches.Value  # Prints the what the pattern matched
}
```

This yields:

```
line before:  line2
matched part: line3
line before:  line5
matched part: line3
```

- `$teststring -split '\r?\n'` splits the multi-line string into an array of lines:

  - Note: What line-break sequences your here-document uses (LF-only vs. CRLF) depends on the enclosing script file; regex `\r?\n` handles either style.
- Note that it is crucial to use the *pipeline* to provide `Select-String`'s input; if you used `-InputObject`, the array would be coerced back to a single string.

---

**`Select-String` is convenient, but *slow*.**
Especially for a single string already in memory, **a solution using the .NET Framework's [`[Regex]::Matches()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will perform much better**, though it is **more complex**.

Note that PowerShell's own `-match` and `-replace` operators are built on the same .NET class, but do not expose all of its functionality; `-match` - which does report capture groups in the automatic `$Matches` variable - is not an option here, because it only ever returns *1* match.

<sup>The following is essentially the same approach as in [mjolinor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683357/45375) answer, but with several problems corrected[1].</sup>

```
# Note: The sample string is defined so that it contains LF-only (\n)
#       line breaks, merely to simplify the regex below for illustration.
#       If your script file use LF-only line breaks, the 
#       `-replace '\r?\n', "`n" call isn't needed.
$teststring = @"
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line3
line6
"@ -replace '\r?\n', "`n" 

[Regex]::Matches($teststring, '(?:^|(.*)\n).*(line3)') | ForEach-Object { 
  "line before:  " + $_.Groups[1].Value
  "matched part: " + $_.Groups[2].Value
}
```

- Regex `(?:^|(.*)\n).*(line3)` uses 2 capture groups (`(...)`) to capture both the (matching part of) the line to match and the line before (`(?:...)` is an auxiliary *non*-capturing group that is needed for precedence):

  - `(?:^|(.*)\n)` matches either the very start of the string (`^`) or (`|`) any - possibly empty - sequence of non-newline characters (`.*`) followed by a newline (`\n`); this ensures that the line to match is also found when there is *no* preceding line (i.e., of the line to match is the *first* one).
  - `(line3)` is the group defining the line to match; it is preceded by `.*` to match the behavior in the question, where pattern `line3` is found even it is only *part* of a line.

    - If you want only *full* lines to match, use the following regex instead:
      `(?:^|(.*)\n)(line3)(?:\n|$)`
- `[Regex]::Matches()` finds *all* matches and returns them as a collection of [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, which the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet call can then operate on to extract the capture-group matches (`$_.Groups[<n>].Value`).

---

<sup>[1] As of this writing:

- There is no need to match *twice* - the enclosing `if ($teststring -match $pattern) { ... }` is unnecessary.

- Inline option `(?m)` is not needed, because `.` does *not* match newlines *by default*.

- `(.+?)` captures only *nonempty lines* (and `?`, the non-greedy quantifier, is not needed).

- If the line of interest is the *first* line - i.e., if there's no line *before*, it won't be matched.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a multi-line regex, with the `-match` operator:

```
$teststring = @"
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line3
line6
"@

$pattern = 
@'
(?m)
(.+?)
line3
'@


if ($teststring -match $pattern)
  { [Regex]::Matches($teststring,$pattern) |
    foreach {$_.groups[1].value} }
```