# Powershell - Capture and display PREVIOUS line when string match = true

Tags: string, powershell, search

I have a script that captures and displays the line of a string match.  Very simple.  What I need now is the previous line to be displayed.  I may need the previous few lines but for now my task is to just capture and display the previous line once a string match is found.

Here is my current script.  I have no clue how to alter it for my purposes.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$searchWords="NEW", "CATLG", "DELETE"


# List the starting (parent) directory here - the script will search through every file and every sub-directory - starting from the one listed below  
Get-Childitem -Path "C:\src\" -Include "*.job"  -Recurse | 
  Select-String -Pattern $searchWords | 

# the output will contain the [Found] word, the document it found it in and the line contents/line number containing the word
    Select Filename,Line,@{n='SearchWord';e={$_.Pattern}}, LineNumber
```

Comment: Do you want the previous line in a separate property/column in the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell: Select line preceding a match -- Select-String -Context issue when using input string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682017/powershell-select-line-preceding-a-match-select-string-context-issue-when-u)

Comment: I do not need to separate them by a column or anything like that.  Just have them print on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add `-Context 1` to your [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) to also capture 1 line before each matching line.
- In your [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (a built-in alias of which is `select`), replace property name `Line` with a [calculated expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that retrieves that line via the `.Context.PreContext` property of the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that `Select-String` outputs:

```bash
Get-Childitem -Path "C:\src" -Include "*.job"  -Recurse | 
  Select-String -Context 1 -Pattern $searchWords | 
  Select-Object Filename,
                @{n='LineBefore';e={$_.Context.PreContext[0]}},
                @{n='SearchWord';e={$_.Pattern}},
                LineNumber
```

Note:

- `-Context` accepts *two* arguments: the first one specifies how many lines to capture *before*, and the second for how many to capture *after*; e.g., `-Context 1, 2` captures one line before, and 2 lines after each match, reflected as arrays of strings in  `.Context.PreContext` and `.Context.PostContext`, respectively.
- **`-Context` only works meaningfully with *line-by-line* input**:

  - When you specify *files* for `Select-String` to search through:

    - Either: By providing [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances such as via [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), as in your case.
    - Or: By using `Select-String`'s own `-Path` or `-LiteralPath` parameter (which doesn't support *recursion*, however)
  - When you provide *individual lines* as input, such as via an *array* (stream) of lines (as opposed to a *multi-line* string).

    - Note that while [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) (*without* using `-Raw`) does provide a stream of lines, it is much faster to use `Get-ChildItem` to pipe a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance describing that file instead.